# How to differentiate a light-cone integral in relativity?

Tags: integration, derivatives, change-of-variable, general-relativity, special-relativity

Consider the following integral
$$
\int_{V_X(v)}I(Y)\,dY\tag1
$$
In [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) coordinates $x_\pm=x\mp vt$, where $t$ is time and $v\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $V_X(v)$ is the past light cone, given, by
$$
V_X(v)=\{Y\text{ such that }x_+\leq y_+,y_-\leq x_-\}
$$
Hence, integral $(1)$ can be given by
$$
 \int_{x_+\leq y_+,y_-\leq x_-} I(y_+,y_-)dy_+dy_-.
$$
How can I obtain the time derivative
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{x_+\leq y_+,y_-\leq x_-} I(y_+,y_-)dy_+dy_-
$$
Is there a closed formula?